# Using $(this) after .replaceWith()

Tags: jquery, this, replacewith

Please consider the below HTML and Javascript. In the script, I am replacing an **a** tag with a **p** tag. I am expecting the alert() function to return the contents of the **p** tag but instead it returns the contents of the original **a** tag which no longer exists.

How can I reference the new element?

**HTML:**

```
<a href="">This is a link</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").each(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith('<p>New Paragraph</p>');
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do it directly with [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/), but you can create it separately. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").each(function() {
        var p = $('<p>New Paragraph</p>');
        $(this).replaceWith(p);
        alert(p.text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `replaceAll` method instead, which returns the new content instead of the original content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").each(function() {
    alert($('<p>New Paragraph</p>').replaceAll($(this)).text());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert($(this).replaceWith('<p>New Paragraph</p>').text());
```

Comment: This won't work, `.replaceWith()` returns the previous object, the `<a>`, not the `<p>` it replaced it with.

Comment: That doesn't work. The `replaceWith` method returns the original jQuery object with the original element, not a new jQuery object with the new element. http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/