# jQuery replaceWith not keeping the link to the element in the DOM?

Tags: jquery, html, replacewith

```
var el = $(this); // it's a form
```

At some point:

```
el.replaceWith('<p>Loading...</p>');
```

Later:

```
el.replaceWith(output);
```

Apparently el doesn't exist anymore after the first replaceWith...

Can I keep somehow `el`, obviously with the new content ?

Comment: You could use `.html()` to replace the inside of the element without replacing the element itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original `el` has been removed and replaced by `replaceWith`. Create a new reference, using the return value of `replaceWith`:

```
var el = $(this); // it's a form
el = el.replaceWith('<p>Loading...</p>');
              //`el.replaceWith()` returns the new element
el = el.replaceWith(output);
```

If you intended to replace the inner content with the new element, while keeping the form, use:

```
el.html(""); //Clear html
el.append('<p>Loading...</p>');
```

Comment: thanks, I've found out that replaceAll does what I want: `el = $('<p>loading...</p>').replaceAll(el);`

Comment: replaceWith seems to return the element that was REMOVED, not the new element, check: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Comment: also check this question at SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892861/replacing-an-element-and-returning-the-new-one-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

jquery's replaceWith returns the replaced element, not the new one

http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/

you should do something like this:

```
var el = $(this); // it's a form
var $p = $('<p>Loading...</p>');

el.replaceWith($p);

// now el is unhooked from the dom, that is el.parent() === []
// it is $p who is now hooked, check with $p.parent() === (some node)

//so you should reassing it
el = $p;

// later on

el.replaceWith(output); // but remenber, once again el is unhooked
```

also, make sure to check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/892915/47633